# Parsing a text file with Python and split()

Tags: python, list

I'm sure there's an easy answer to this, I just can't seem to figure out what's the best solution.

I have a text file that contains the following: a username and a password. An example is below:

```
mcgoga12,password
shelby12,password1
```

I want to open this file, and read in the file. However, I want to store the username (mcgoga12, etc...) and the password (password, etc...) in two separate lists.

Does anyone have a specific suggestion as to how to parse this?

Here's what I've tried:

```
with open("credentials.txt", "r") as infile:
    users = infile.read().rsplit(',',3)
    print users
```

However, I keep getting this output (clearly its not separating it)

```
['mcgoga12', 'password\nshelby12', 'password1\n']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new lines are there in the file, which have to be explicitly removed with `strip` family of functions. We use `rstrip` and then we split the `line` based on `,` which will give us a list which has username and its corresponding password. Now, we do this for all the lines and finally transform the `data` with `zip` function, like this

```
with open("credentials.txt", "r") as infile:
    data = [line.rstrip().split(",") for line in infile]
    usernames, passwords = zip(*data)
    print usernames, passwords
    # ('mcgoga12', 'shelby12') ('password', 'password1')
```

If we print just the `data`, it would look something like this

```
[['mcgoga12', 'password'], ['shelby12', 'password1']]
```

and when we `zip` it with unpacking, it will become

```
('mcgoga12', 'shelby12') ('password', 'password1')
```

when we say zipping with unpacking, it means that we are unpacking the sequence as parameters to the function. For example,

```
zip(*data)
```

is just a shorthand notation for

```
zip(data[0], data[1]...)
```